# BJT Circuit Current

Tags: current, resistors, bjt, npn, pnp

I have  a question regarding the circuit below.

I am unsure how to calculate the current flowing through the 1k resistor.

I think it is reasonable assumption that the collector of the PNP BJT must be sitting around (5-0.7) = 4.3V as it's base is tied back round to the collector (and assuming the PNP BJT is fully on).

But what assumption should we make about the voltage on the collector on the NPN BJT? I know it is the same as the voltage dropped across the 1k resistor, but I don't know the current flowing through it to work out the voltage dropped.

Is the current through the 1k resistor simply controlled by the base current on the NPN BJT, where the (base current x beta) gives the current through the 1k resistor?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do some circuit analysis on it. What do you know about the relationship of \$\beta\$ (and perhaps \$\alpha\$) and the currents of a BJT? This is really just Kirchhoff's Current Law, assuming of course each transistor is in active region.

Comment: You certainly cannot assume that both BJTs are "fully on" (saturated?). In fact, with the component parameters shown, neither one is fully on.

Comment: As written, your question doesn't make sense. Your stated assumptions are not consistent with the schematic and the marked values.

Comment: @KingDuken are you talking about circuit analysis with the pnp or the npn transistor first?

Comment: More like this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/462469/fan-control-circuit-not-working-fan-remains-on/462475?noredirect=1#comment1165215_462475

Comment: I understand the circuit doesn’t fit the question, I didn’t design it. It’s a question I have been given.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I think we can interpret "fully on" as indicating forward active operation in this case.

Comment: @ThePhoton: How could they be anything other than "fully on" in that sense?

Comment: @DaveTweed, I was replying to where you said that "neither one is fully on".

Comment: @ThePhoton: Then I don't understand your point. They are both operating in "forward active" mode.

Comment: @David. that's why it seems whoever posed the question was using the term "fully on" to mean they're in forward active operation. You assumed "fully on" means saturated and from that concluded the question is not self-consistent. My point is, if you make a different interpretation of the question statement, the question is self-consistent after all.

Comment: @ThePhoton: And my point is that if interpreted in that sense, there's no point in saying *"Assume that both BJT's are fully on"* at all. No assumption is required -- it is something that can be deduced directly from the rest of the information already given. And what would "not fully on" mean anyway?

Comment: @DaveTweed, fair enough, you could deduce it from the given information. Possibly the instructor was giving that information so that students wouldn't have to step through a formal process they've been taught like, "First assume cut-off operation, analyze the circuit and check for consistency. Now assume forward active for one of the two devices, ... etc., etc."

Comment: @ThePhoton For what it's worth, I interpret "fully on" for a BJT to mean saturated. I guess the bottom line is that the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, without context, I'd interpret it the same. In this context, it's apparent whoever wrote it meant forward active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what assumption should we make about the voltage on the collector on the NPN BJT?

You don't need to make any assumption about the collector voltage of the NPN.

You have enough information to find its base current, and you know its \$\beta\$. From this you can answer the question without even calculating the collector voltage. (Although you should calculate it to verify your assumptions about the operating state)

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I thought there was another way, but I am familiar with this method.